# How to set different line spread for table of contents than the rest of document?

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing

I am writing my final paper on university, and we have to use double line spread and Times New Roman.
If I set `\linespread{1.6}` in the preamble everything is fine, except that in the table of contents `\section`s get huge spacings. If I set the line spread after the `\tableofcontents` tag noting happens, line spread remains normal.

Is there any possibility to keep normal line spread in the TOC only?

Comment: `\linespread` after `\begin{document}` needs `\selectfont` to become active. See [fntguide](http://ctan.org/pkg/fntguide) for more information about this and the answers below for recommended solutions to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the featrures provided by the `setspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\singlespacing
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}
\section{Section Five}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\doublespacing

\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}
\section{Section Five}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In your second example, I would just use `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}`, which results in exactly the same thing as your current code ([`\DeclareOption{doublespacing}{\AtEndOfPackage{\doublespacing}}`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/setspace/setspace.sty), l. 285) , but it's more concise.

Comment: @doncherry: no, they do not produce the same result; in my second code `\doublespacing` does not affect the ToC.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your first example, of course; must've been holding my laptop the wrong way round again. So, instead of `\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing`, I'm suggesting `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}`.

Comment: @doncherry: Ah. Well, yes that would be another way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `setspace` package. Simply add `\usepackage{setspace}` to the preamble and `\doublespacing` after the table of contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\doublespacing
\section{one}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{two}
\lipsum[5-8]
\section{three}
\lipsum[9-12]
\end{document}
```

[image: Differently spaced toc]